# WebClient Add Authorization

Tags: c#

I am trying to post to a REST web service in order to update new stock prices. I am facing an error each time i post the URL in the code using `WebClient`. The remote server has a Bad Request(400). Each time I'm trying to post the parameters I get the Bad Request(400) error. The webservice requires a header with an api key which is the parameter  key in the method signature.

```
public string CompanyService(string key, string c, string pc, string po, string ph, string pl, string pb, string pv, string pd, string pt)
{
    string SmsStatusMsg = string.Empty;
    try
    {

        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string URL = "";

        URL = "http://166.63.10.232:88/finsec/api/v1/setCompanyPrices";

        string data = "company_name=" + c + "&price_close=" + pc + "&price_open=" + po + "&price_high=" + ph + "&price_low=" + pl + "&price_best=" + pb + "&price_volume=" + pv + "&price_date=" + pd + "&price_time=" + pt +"";

        client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + key);

        SmsStatusMsg = client.UploadString(URL, "POST", data);

        if (SmsStatusMsg.Contains("<br>"))
        {
            SmsStatusMsg = SmsStatusMsg.Replace("<br>", ", ");
        }
    }
    catch (WebException e1)
    {
        SmsStatusMsg = e1.Message;
    }
    catch (Exception e2)
    {
        SmsStatusMsg = e2.Message;
    }
    return SmsStatusMsg;
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide some exception details?

Comment: **1.** When posting on Stack Overflow, please take the time to format your question properly. It's a question of basic courtesy and it will also help people understand your question more quickly, so you're doing yourself a favor. **2.** You don't need to include commented-out code. Since it's commented out, it won't have any runtime effects, so it cannot be relevant for the issue you describe. Remove it before posting. **3.** So you have an error with `WebClient`. Why don't you tell us about it? **4.** You're mentioning "authorization" in the subject line. How does it relate to your question?

Comment: I want to post to Rest api service that requires a header with a token key using WebClient and it is meant to be a post. Each time I try I get an error the remote server has a Bad Request (400). I need help adding the authorization header to the WebClient so I can post my stock prices

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use WebClient? I would recommend using the HttpClient class was created specfically to support REST API's. http://www.diogonunes.com/blog/webclient-vs-httpclient-vs-httpwebrequest/. However, it won't make too much difference given your scenario. Second, 400 BadRequest often means your URL, or the data you have provided is wrong. If only the authorization header was incorrect I would expect you would receive a 401 Unauthorized response.